# Issues with predict function when building a CART model via CrossValidation using the train command

Tags: r, classification, r-caret, rpart

I am trying to build a CART model via cross validation using the train function of "caret" package.

My data is 4500 x 110 data frame, where all the predictor variables (except the first two, UserId and YOB (Year of Birth) which I am not using for model building) are factors with 2 levels except the dependent variable which is of type integer (although has only two values 1 and 0). Gender is one of the independent variables.

When I ran rpart command to get CART model (using the package "rpart"), i didn't have any problem with the predict function. However, I wanted to improve the model via cross validation, and so used the train function from the package "caret" with the following command:

```
tr = train(y ~ ., data = subImpTrain, method = "rpart", trControl = tr.control, tuneGrid = cp.grid)
```

This build the model with the following warning

```
Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  :
  There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
```

But it did give me a final model (best.tree). However, when I am trying to run the predict function using the following command:

```
best.tree.pred = predict(best.tree, newdata = subImpTest)
```

on the test data, it is giving me the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'GenderMale' not found
```

The Gender variable has two values: Female, Male

Can anybody help me understand the error

Comment: Looks like it's looking for the column GenderMale. Can you compare the variables in your Train and Test sets?  what's the output of `identical(names(subImpTrain),names(subImpTest))`

Comment: They are similar, and that confuses even more.

Answer (score 1):

As @lorelai suggested, `caret` dummy-codes your variables if you supply it a formula. An alternative is to provide it the variables themselves, like so:

```
tr = train(y = subImpTrain$y, x = subImpTrain[, -subImpTrain$y],
           method = "rpart", trControl = tr.control, tuneGrid = cp.grid)
```

More importantly, however, you shouldn't use `predict.rpart` and instead use `predict.train`, like so:

```
predict(tr, subImpTest)
```

In which case it would work just fine with the formula interface.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem in the past, although concerning another algorithm.
Basically, some algorithms transform the factor variables into dummy variables and rename them accordingly.
My solution was to create my own dummies and leave them in numerical format.
I read that decision trees manage to work properly even so.